# Completion of a ring and the canonical map

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

Given a noetherian ring $R$ and an ideal $I$.

Questions: Can $R$ be isomorphic to the $I$-adic complection $\hat{R}$ of $R$ without the canonical map $R \rightarrow \hat{R}$ being an isomorphism?

A non-noetherian example was found by Denis T., so I restricted the question to the noetherian case after an edit.

Posted also on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3403968/completion-of-a-ring-and-the-canonical-map

Comment: As posted, trivial non-noetherian example is the direct sum of countable amount of $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z_p$. Complete at $(p)$ in a copy of $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @DenisT. Thanks, do you want to make this to an answer? I highlight the noetherian part then.

Comment: Well, I'm interested in question myself, so I'd rather wait for more satisfactory answer.